# Ruby code to iterate over every n-th element of an array and print it until all elements are printed?

Tags: ruby

I am asked to write some code in Ruby that iterates over every n-th element of an array and prints it until all elements of the array are printed.

The question reads:
Imagine an iterator that accesses an array in strides and runs some code at each stride. If the strides reach the end of the array then they simply begin anew from the array's beginning.
For example:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
x.stride(1) do |elem|; puts elem; end # prints 0,1,2,3,4
x.stride(2) do |elem|; puts elem; end # prints 0,2,4,1,3
x.stride(8) do |elem|; puts elem; end # prints 0,3,1,4,2
[].stride(2) do |elem|; puts elem; end # does not print anything, but the code is correct
```

Assume that the stride is equal or greater than 1, and that both the stride and the array's size are not a integral/whole multiple of each other, meaning that the whole array can be printed using a given stride. Fill in the code that's missing:

```
class Array
    def stride(step)
        numelems = ... # size of the array
        ...
    end
end
```

It is obvious that `numelemns = self.length()`. However am having trouble with the rest.
I am going to try writing some code in Python that accomplishes this task, but I am afraid that I will not be able to translate it to Ruby.

Any ideas? The answer should not be more than 4-5 lines long as the question is one that our proffessor gave us to solve in a couple of minutes.

---

A solution to this is provided below (thanks [@user3574603](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574603/user3574603)):

```
class Array
  def stride(step)
      yield self[0]
      (self * step).map.with_index do |element, index|
          next element if index == 0
          yield element if index % step == 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't this just do `self[i % len]` where you're doing `i += stride` and then `yield` that. Wrap that in `self.length.times do` and you're good.

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails? Also, the `stride` method seems to always loop forever, according to the specification (unless the array is empty).

Comment: The `stride` method does not loop forever.

Comment: This will only yield all elements if the _step_ value and the array's _size_ are coprime. Otherwise, you will run in circles and visit the same elements over and over again, e.g. `[0,1,2,3].stride(2)` would yield `0, 2, 0, 2, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This almost does what I think you want but breaks if the step is <strike>array.length + 1</strike> `array.length` (but you mention that we should assume the stride is not a multiply of the array length).

```
class Array
  def exhaustive_stride(step)
    (self * step).map.with_index do |element, index|
      next element if index == 0

      element if index % step == 0
    end.compact
  end
end
```

```
x.exhaustive_stride 1
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
x.exhaustive_stride 2
#=> [0, 2, 4, 1, 3] 
x.exhaustive_stride 8
#=> [0, 3, 1, 4, 2] 
[].exhaustive_stride 2
#=> []
```

Using the example array, it breaks when the stride is 5.

```
[0,1,2,3,4].exhaustive_stride 5
#=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Note**

This works but the intermediate array makes it highly inefficient. Consider other answers.

Comment: This works perfectly, even when the step is `array.length + 1`.
Using the example array `x = [0,1,2,3,4]` that has a size of 5 with a step of 6, it prints `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant when the step size is the same as the array length. (Too tired)

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes that `arr.size` and `n` are not both even numbers and `arr.size` is not a multiple of `n`.

```
def striding(arr, n)
  sz = arr.size
  result = '_' * sz
  idx = 0
  sz.times do
    result[idx] = arr[idx].to_s
    puts "S".rjust(idx+1)        
    puts result
    idx = (idx + n) % sz
  end
end
```

---

```
striding [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6], 7
S
1______________
       S
1______8_______
              S
1______8______6
      S
1_____78______6
             S
1_____78_____56
     S
1____678_____56
            S
1____678____456
    S
1___5678____456
           S
1___5678___3456
   S
1__45678___3456
          S
1__45678__23456
  S
1_345678__23456
         S
1_345678_123456
 S
12345678_123456
        S
123456789123456
```

---

Here is an example where `arr.size` is a multiple of `n`.

```
striding [1,2,3,4,5,6], 3  
S
1_____
   S
1__4__
S
1__4__
   S
1__4__
S
1__4__
   S
1__4__
```

---

Here is an example where `arr.size` and `n` are both even numbers.

```
striding [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 6  
S
1_______
      S
1_____7_
    S
1___5_7_
  S
1_3_5_7_
S
1_3_5_7_
      S
1_3_5_7_
    S
1_3_5_7_
  S
1_3_5_7_
```

Comment: I like the visualization!

Answer (score 1):

> Imagine an iterator that accesses an array in strides and runs some code at each stride. If the strides reach the end of the array then they simply begin anew from the array's beginning.

Based on this specification, `stride` will always iterate forever, unless the array is empty. But that is not a problem, since we can easily [`take`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) only the amount of elements we need.

In fact, that is a *good* design: producing an infinite stream of values lets the consumer decide how many they need.

A simple solution could look like this:

```ruby
module CoreExtensions
  module EnumerableExtensions
    module EnumerableWithStride
      def stride(step = 1)
        return enum_for(__callee__, step) unless block_given?

        enum = cycle

        loop do
          yield(enum.next)
          (step - 1).times { enum.next }
        end

        self
      end
    end
  end
end

Enumerable.include(CoreExtensions::EnumerableExtensions::EnumerableWithStride)
```

A couple of things to note here:

I chose to add the `stride` method to [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerable.html) instead of [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html). `Enumerable` is Ruby's work horse for iteration and there is nothing in the `stride` method that requires `self` to be an `Array`. `Enumerable` is simply the better place for it.

Instead of directly monkey-patching `Enumerable`, I put the method in a separate `module`. That makes it easier to debug code for others. If they see a `stride` method they don't recognize, and inspect the inheritance chain of the object, they will immediately see a module named `EnumerableWithStride` in the inheritance chain and can make the reasonable assumption that the method is probably coming from here:

```ruby
[].stride
# Huh, what is this `stride` method? I have never seen it before.
# And it is not documented on https://ruby-doc.org/

# Let's investigate:
[].class.ancestors
#=> [
#     Array,
#     Enumerable,
#     CoreExtensions::EnumerableExtensions::EnumerableWithStride,
#     Object,
#     Kernel,
#     BasicObject
#   ]

# So, we're confused about a method named `stride` and we
# found a module whose name includes `Stride`.
# We can reasonably guess that somewhere in the system, 
# there must be a file named
# `core_extensions/enumerable_extensions/enumerable_with_stride.rb`.

# Or, we could ask the method directly:
meth = [].method(:stride)

meth.owner
#=> CoreExtensions::EnumerableExtensions::EnumerableWithStride

meth.source_location
#=> [
#     'core_extensions/enumerable_extensions/enumerable_with_stride.rb',
#     6
#   ]
```

For an empty array, nothing happens:

```ruby
[].stride(2, &method(:p))
#=> []
```

`stride` just returns `self` (just like `each` does) and the block is never executed.

For a non-empty array, we get an infinite stream of values:

```ruby
x.stride(&method(:p))
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 0
# 1
# …

x.stride(2, &method(:p))
# 0
# 2
# 4
# 1
# 3
# 0
# 2
# …

x.stride(8, &method(:p))
# 0
# 3
# 1
# 4
# 2
# 0
# 3
# …
```

The nice thing about this infinite stream of values is that *we*, as the consumer can freely choose how many elements we want. For example, if I want 10 elements, I simply `take` 10 elements:

```ruby
x.stride(3).take(10)
#=> [0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2]
```

This works because, like all well-behaved iterators, our `stride` method returns an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerator.html) in case no block is supplied:

```ruby
enum = x.stride(2)
#=> #<Enumerator: ...>

enum.next
#=> 0

enum.next
#=> 2

enum.next
#=> 4

enum.next
#=> 1

enum.next
#=> 3

enum.next
#=> 0

enum.next
#=> 2
```

So, if we want to implement the requirement "until all the elements of the array are printed":

> I am asked to write some code in Ruby that iterates over every n-th element of an array and prints it until all elements of the array are printed.

We could implement that something like this:

```ruby
x.stride.take(x.length).each(&method(:p))
x.stride(2).take(x.length).each(&method(:p))
x.stride(8).take(x.length).each(&method(:p))
```

This is a pretty simplistic implementation, though. Here, we simply print as many elements as there are elements in the original array.

We could implement a more sophisticated logic using [`Enumerable#take_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while) that keeps track of which elements have been printed and which haven't, and only stops if all elements are printed. But we can easily prove that after `x.length` iterations either all elements have been printed or there will never be all elements printed (if the stride size is an integral multiple of the array length or vice versa). So, this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that uses recursion. Not the most efficient but one way of doing it.

```
class Array
  def exhaustive_stride(x, r = [])
    return [] if self.empty?

    r << self[0] if r.empty?

    while x > self.length
      x -= self.length 
    end

    r << self[x]
    x += x

    return r if r.count == self.count

    stride(x, r)
  end
end
```

```
[0,1,2,3,4].exhaustive_stride 1
#=> [0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
[0,1,2,3,4].exhaustive_stride 2
#=> [0, 2, 4, 3, 1]
[0,1,2,3,4].exhaustive_stride 8
#=> [0, 3, 1, 2, 4]
[].exhaustive_stride 2
#=> []
[0,1,2,3,4].exhaustive_stride 100_000_001
#=> [0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
def stride(ary, step)
  raise ArgumentError unless step.gcd(ary.size) == 1

  Array.new(ary.size) { |i| ary[(i * step) % ary.size] }
end
```

Example:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

stride(x, 1) #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
stride(x, 2) #=> [0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
stride(x, 8) #=> [0, 3, 1, 4, 2]

stride(x, -1) #=> [0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

First of all, the guard clause checks whether `step` and `ary.size` are [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) to ensure that all elements can be visited via `step`.

`Array.new(ary.size)` creates a new array of the same size as the original array. The elements are then retrieved from the original array by multiplying the element's index by `step` and then performing a modulo operation using the array's size.

Having `% arr.size` is equivalent to fetching the elements from a cyclic array, e.g. for a `step` value of `2`:

```
 0     1     2     3     4
 |     |     |     |     |
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
```

---

To turn this into an instance method for `Array` you merely replace `ary` with `self` (which can be omitted most of the time):

```
class Array
  def stride(step)
    raise ArgumentError unless step.gcd(size) == 1

    Array.new(size) { |i| self[(i * step) % size] }
  end
end
```